# Xamarin Forms and Azure Mobile Apps: CancelledBySyncStoreError Exception from PullAsync

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to reproduce the post "Getting Started with Azure Mobile Apps’ Easy Tables" from *James Montemagno*. However I'd like to make some changes and/or additions, so that the result fits into my personal interests. Everything works fine except one issue:

**PullAsync** (from **IMobileServiceSyncTable**) throws an **CancelledBySyncStoreError** exception !!!

(I'm executing the Xamarin Forms App as an Android App - target decice is a Nexus 7 with Android Version 5.1.1)

Details are as follows:

In the  Azure Portal I've setup an Easy Table. The schema is as follows:

[Azure Schema Definition of Easy Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wTJw.png)

The table in the Portal seems to be correctly established, because I can integrate the remote table in Visual Studio (2013) Server Explorer. Schema details as seen from the Visual Studio are as follows:

[Table Schema as seen by Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wREVN.png)

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FirstHighScores] (
    [id]        NVARCHAR (255)     CONSTRAINT [DF_FirstHighScores_id] DEFAULT (CONVERT([nvarchar](255),newid(),(0))) NOT NULL,
    [createdAt] DATETIMEOFFSET (3) CONSTRAINT [DF_FirstHighScores_createdAt] DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetimeoffset](3),sysutcdatetime(),(0))) NOT NULL,
    [updatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET (3) NULL,
    [version]   ROWVERSION         NOT NULL,
    [deleted]   BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [Score]     FLOAT (53)         NULL,
    [PlayedAt]  DATETIMEOFFSET (3) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

As you can see, I've added three columns in the portal manually: **Name**, **Score** and **PlayedAt**.
The corresponding SQL data types are **String**, **Number** and **Date**.
All of the remaining schema entries have been generated automatically by the Azure Portal scheme designer.

Next some infos about my Xamarin Forms App:

The model class of my Azure Easy Table is as follows
(Azure Table name and C# class name are the same (!)):

```
namespace AzureHighScoresFirstApp
{
    public class FirstHighScores
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Version]
        public string AzureVersion { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime PlayedAt { get; set; }

        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following **Initialize**-Method runs **without** (!) exception:

```
public async Task Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        this.mobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://peterstestapp.azurewebsites.net");

        // setup local sqlite store and intialize our table
        const string path = "syncstore.db";
        MobileServiceSQLiteStore store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<FirstHighScores>();

        await this.mobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        // get our sync table that will call out to azure
        this.scoresTable = this.mobileService.GetSyncTable<FirstHighScores>();

        Debug.WriteLine("Did Initialize");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The **SyncScores**-Method looks as follows:

```
public async Task SyncScores()
{
    try
    {
        IMobileServiceTableQuery<FirstHighScores> query = this.scoresTable.CreateQuery();

        await this.scoresTable.PullAsync("allScores", query);  <== **crashes**

        await this.mobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();      <== not reached
    }
    catch (MobileServicePushFailedException ex)
    {
        string ErrorString = string.Format("Push failed because of sync errors: {0} errors, message: {1}",
            ex.PushResult.Errors.Count, ex.Message);

        Debug.WriteLine(ErrorString + " - " + ex.PushResult.Status);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception SyncScores: " + ex);
    }
}
```

The **SyncScores**- and the **Initialize**-method share the following instance variables:

```
private MobileServiceClient mobileService;
private IMobileServiceSyncTable<FirstHighScores> scoresTable;
```

If I call **SyncScores** (within a *Read*- or *Write*-Method from my Xamarin Forms Client), an **MobileServicePushFailedException**-Exception with the error message '**CancelledBySyncStoreError**' is thrown.

In my opinion the Exception is thrown, because the SQLite-Client in the Xamarin Forms App, being instructed about the table scheme through the definition of my C#-class '**FirstHighScores**' and the remote table scheme of the corresponding Azure Easy Table don't exactly match.

But I can't figure out the difference ....

Sorry, some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround by myself.

Maybe during development of my app, some details according to the data base scheme could have been altered (although I really can't remember this).

When the design of the database model was stable, I just created a new **MobileServiceSQLiteStore** object
(means: I've choosen *another* name for the database storage) ... and the synchronization methods worked fine!

Comment: If you uninstall the app from the device, the database will be deleted.